# DataTable compute method returns DBNull for ABS function

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to make a dynamic calculation using `DataTable.Compute` method and I pass in the the following text as input `abs(-1)`. The corresponding code would be:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
String calculation = dt.Compute("abs(-1)", null);
```

The output is surprisingly always null or better said `DbNull`. This is while when I convert this to `iif(-1 > 0, 1, -1)` the `Compute` method works as expected.

However, I need an Absolute Value function and I am unsure if this isn't the right way to use it or if that is a potential bug in .Net Core. How could this be possibly solved?

Comment: Unfortunately, the Compute() method supports what DataColumn.Expression does, and the list does not contain ABS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @OguzOzgul: Then why on earth did they contemplate the `Abs` function in there or why does it not throw any exception? I suppose if it isn't implemented then the method MUST throw an exception as it does when I pass an unsupported functions let's say 'ABC'. This could be a substantial bug and I guess I have to report it at their github.

Comment: Interstingly, it does throw an exception when I pass DFE(-1): "The expression contains undefined function call DFE()." The source code shows that Abs is a valid function, and we can also see that it is evaluated as expected (return Math.Abs on parameter), but somehow (Trying to read the code more is overkill I think) returns DBNull https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/System.Data/System/Data/Filter/FunctionNode.cs

Comment: Also, dt.Columns["Col2"].Expression = "Len(StrCol1)"; works, while with dt.Columns["Col2"].Expression = "Abs(IntCol1)"; all the values in Col2 are null.

Answer (score -1):

I have created the following statement:
"IIF("+Col1+ "-" + Col2 + "< 0, ("+Col1 + "-" + Col2+")*-1,"+ Col1 + "-" + Col2+")"); // ABS Workaround